# Here is the below working fine in firefox and not working in chrome in selenium?

Tags: selenium

Firefox:
     package com.webdriver;
        import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
        import org.openqa.selenium.By;
        import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
        import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
        import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

```
    public class OpenandClosenewtab {

        public static void main(String[] a) throws InterruptedException {
            // Initialize driver  
            WebDriver dr = new FirefoxDriver();
            //Maximize browser window   
            dr.manage().window().maximize();
            //Go to URL  
            dr.get("http://www.google.com");
            //Set  timeout  
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            // Open new tab  
    dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
            //Go to URL  
            dr.get("http://www.gmail.com");
            //Set new tab timeout  
    dr.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            // Do some operation          
            //dr.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
            dr.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abdulazeem5513");
            dr.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
            dr.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("azeem_#5513");
            dr.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
            dr.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='gb_1a gbii']")).click();
            dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='gb_71']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            // Close new tab  
    dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "w");

            // Switch first tab  
            dr.switchTo().defaultContent();
            Thread.sleep(2000);
            // Write search String  
            dr.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("welcome to salesforce");
            // Click on Search button          
           dr.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='lsb']")).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000);

            // Browser close    
            dr.close();
        }

    }
```

chrome:

```
package com.webdriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Openclosegmail {

    public static void main(String[] a) throws InterruptedException {
        // Initialize driver  
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Mine New\\1EclipseWorkPath1\\Sprint 10\\src\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver dr = new ChromeDriver();
        //Maximize browser window   
        dr.manage().window().maximize();
        //Go to URL  
        dr.get("https://www.google.com");
        //Set  timeout  

        // Open new tab  
dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "t");
        //Go to URL  
        dr.get("https://www.gmail.com");
        //Set new tab timeout  

        // Do some operation          
        //dr.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        dr.findElement(By.id("Email")).sendKeys("abdulazeem5513");
        dr.findElement(By.id("next")).click();
        dr.findElement(By.id("Passwd")).sendKeys("azeem_#5513");
        dr.findElement(By.id("signIn")).click();
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='gb_1a gbii']")).click();
        dr.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='gb_71']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Close new tab  
dr.findElement(By.cssSelector("body")).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "w");

        // Switch first tab  
        dr.switchTo().defaultContent();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        // Write search String  
        dr.findElement(By.id("lst-ib")).sendKeys("welcome to salesforce");
        // Click on Search button          
       dr.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='lsb']")).click();
        Thread.sleep(2000);

        // Browser close    
        dr.close();
    }

}
```

Comment: what is not working? which code/operation is not working. post only relevent code and post detail version of issue you are facing

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with switching tab after opening new tab. 
You can switch tab using `driver.switchTo().window(windowHandler);`